# Execute different server.js file from current server in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm developing a simple app with nodejs. The thing is that the first thing I do is to run a **server.js file** which loads an **html form** and checks if the entered information is valid.

After authentication, I'm planning to run another **server.js** (starting it from the original server.js file) in a subfolder for starting the real application.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely, check out [`child_process.spawn`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html).

```
child_process.spawn("node", ["server.js"]);
process.exit(); // ends auth server
```

Comment: I'm trying to use it, but I guess it is not launching the secondary server.js file (maybe it has to do with the path to that file)